# Loading an image of a website that contains redirects

Tags: android, web

I am currently doing a small app for fun while playing around with the UIs and several other things in android studio. I tried to load a image based on an url with this code:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.connect();
InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
```

However this will throw a FileNotFoundException for certain urls. I am guessing that is due to the webpage checking the client for certain conditions. One example is this image:
https://kissanime.to/Content/Mobile/images/logo.png
It works fine when loading it via the webbrowser though.
I do not own this page, so I do not know what is causing this issues. Is there any way to debug/solve this?

//EDIT: It seems that the website returns a 503 statuscode when using the HttpURLConnection
//EDIT 2: After inspecting the response message it seems like the webpage contains some type of javascript that loads the image after a 5 second delay

Comment: You can use Piccaso. It very easy and simple

Comment: Tried that right now. Unfortunately, this has the same result as using a plain httpConnection.